# C# Arrays vs. Streams

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, stream

When writing functions that operate on a potentially infinite "stream" of data, i.e. bytes, chars, whatever, what are some design considerations in deciding to use Strings/Arrays vs. Streams for the input/output?

Is there a huge performance impact of always writing functions to use streams, and then making overload methods that use stream wrappers (i.e. StringReader/Writer) to return "simple data" like an array or a string that doesnt require disposing and other considerations?

I would think functions operating on arrays are far more convenient because you can "return" a resulting array and you don't usually have to worry about disposing. I assume stream operators are nice because they can operate on an infinite source of data, probably memory-efficient as well.

Comment: Whatever kind of collection or stream class you use (other than LinkedList) ultimately boils down to a byte[] at the core.  The fundamental and only collection type supported by the machine.  Which can be certainly be a painful impedance mismatch, always better to use the ones that are in the toolbox and already do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with binary data of unknown size always use streams. Reading an entire file into a byte array for example is usually bad idea if it can be avoided. Most functions in .Net  that work with binary data such as encryption and compression are built to use streams as input/output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a function to process a stream of data, then why not pass it as an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can then return a stream as an `IEnumerable<T>` in a generator function. In other words using `return yield` to return each result one a ta time.

You can end up with asymptotic improvements in performance in some cases because the evaluation is done as needed.

Comment: I do this for functions that operate on collections of objects (i.e. reference types) in memory, but I'm not sure I like the idea of operating on primitives with this approach. If the stream is designed to omit certain patterns, for example, you would have to implement more than is necessary loops since you can't yield return a bunch of values at once.